# how to create slow query analysis of postgresql in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, postgresql-9.1

Hi how to create and slow query analysis of postgresql in rails.

There is any method to find the slow query in our rails application.

Comment: Rails 3.2 see http://railscasts.com/episodes/318-upgrading-to-rails-3-2?view=asciicast auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds or try newrelic http://newrelic.com/ruby/rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach I would recommend to easily find all the n+1 queries is to use the [bullet](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet) gem.  It will notify you anytime you stumble upon an n+1 query and don't notice it in your logs.  Take its recommendations with a grain of salt but its usually pretty good about telling you when eager loading might be beneficial.

Comment: Similar to bullet - http://railscasts.com/episodes/368-miniprofiler?view=asciicast